# Autopopulate multiselect with Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator with Spring MVC and I have one problem with multiselect (in ManyToMany relation). My base class is Project. Project has, among others, fields: name (String), User(ManyToOne), regions(ManyToMany)

```
class Project {
    .
    private String name;
    private User user;
    private List<Region> regions
    .
}
```

In controller (POST action) I have:

```
public String saveProject(
    @Valid Project project,
    BindingResult bindingResult,
    ModelMap model) {

    //send regions, users etc. to model

    //errors
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        System.out.println(project.getRegions().size());
        //Printed size of regions is identical with selected

        return "templates/project/form";        
    }


    //no errors, save to database etc.

}
```

InitBinder:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder ( WebDataBinder binder )
{
    StringTrimmerEditor stringtrimmer = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringtrimmer);

    binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "regions",new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class){
        @Override
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            Region region = new Region();

            if (element != null) {
                Integer id = Integer.valueOf(element.toString());
                region.setId(id);
            }
            return region;
        }
    });
```

In return form, field 'name' id filled out, user is selected but regions multiselect is **empty**.

More interesting, if object persists in database, in 'edit' form, multiselect is **filled out properly**.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution I found is load full object of region is 'saveProject' action:

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

    System.out.println(project.getRegions().size());
    //Printed size of regions is identical with selected

    if (project.getRegions() != null) {
        List<Region> regionsTemp = new ArrayList<Region>();
        for (Region region1 : project.getRegions()) {
            Region region = Database.findById(region1.getId());
            regionsTemp.add(region);
        }
        project.setRegions(regionsTemp);
    }

    return "templates/project/form";        
}
```

Any other ideas?